# How to switch from one Swiper effect to another with screen size change?

Tags: responsive-design, breakpoints, swiper.js

How do I switch from using the CoverFlow effect in swiper to using the cards effect on a smaller screen? I tried using breakpoints but I didn't work

Answer (score 1):

In fact, [as the doc says](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints), effect won't work with breakpoints. 
A possible workaround is to **change the slider parameters depending on window width.** 
To get the current window width you can use `window.innerWidth` in JavaScript.

It would look like this:

```js
let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
let params;

if(windowWidth <= yourBreakpoint){
    params = { /* small screen params */ }
}else if (windowWidth > yourBreakpoint){
    params = { /* large screen params */ }
}

let swiper = new Swiper(".slider", params);
```

Then you can set `effect: "coverflow"` in small screen params and `effect: "cards"` in large screen params.

*Please note that this solution doesn't work dynamically if the window is resized and needs page refresh.*